# how to add column and set values only for rows that have value from a given list

Tags: python, dataframe

Let say I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ID   size    price
0   1   5      300
1   2   10     500
2   3   20     600
3   4   35     800
4   5   65     900
5   6   70     1000
```

and I want to add a column 'removed' to it, that will have 1 for an 'ID' that is in a given list, and 0 otherwise.

```
ids_wanted = [1,4,6]
```

And the result will be:

```
    ID    size    price   removed
0   1      5       300        1
1   2     10       500        0
2   3     20       600        0
3   4     35       800        1
4   5     65       900        0
5   6     70      1000        1
```

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
i = range(1,7)
s = [5,10,20,35,65,70]
p = [300,500,600,800,900,1000]
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":i,"size":s,"price":p})
ids_wanted = [1,4,6]
df['removed']=['1','0','0','1','0','1']
df
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Can you explain your problem clearly

Comment: I did df['removed']=['1','0','0','1','0','1'] only from demonstration. I want it to do it alone. If an ID is in the list 'ids_wanted', his column 'removed' will be 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mark them dynamically with 0 or 1, you need to change your declaration of the 'removed' column to something like that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
i = range(1,7)
s = [5,10,20,35,65,70]
p = [300,500,600,800,900,1000]
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":i,"size":s,"price":p})
ids_wanted = [1,4,6]
ids = [df['ID'][j] for j in range(len(df['ID']))]
df['removed']=[1 if j in ids_wanted else 0 for j in ids]
```

Thus it sets all ids in ids_wanted to 1, the others to 0.

Comment: Thank you, But the i is not defined. What did you mean by i?

Comment: It's defined in your question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: my ID column is not really i=range(1,7). How do I implement it to the values in the column?

Comment: df['removed'] = ['1' if j in ids_wanted else '0' for j in df['ID']] does not work.

Comment: Look at the changes in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry to bug but I can't find the answer for it. If I would like to change the value if the ID is in ids, else: leave as it is. I tried to do it with "else None" but it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't it now working as expected? ids is now referring to your IDs in the DataFrame and the value for removed is only set to '1' if the given ID is in your ids_wanted, else it's set to '0'.

Comment: It works, But I want to do it in a for loop where in each iteration the 'ids_wanted' are changing and the 'removed' column will receive the same variable with different values. Now the column 'removed' every iteration is set again.